# Non-ASCII BSSID garbled

Tags: ssid

I typed a non-ASCII bssid name in the router settings page in the browser and when trying to connect to it it looks garbled. Can BSSID be non-ASCII? If so, what goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of embedded systems and computers only support standard ascii to read an SSID, some try to convert extended ascii into a character in the regular ascii table, but that doesn't always work.

For example, common practice is that if you use Θ which is theta (233) your device will try to translate it into a  'T' just to keep things readable. However, if you use a symbol it might not do the same and you could end up with '?', random letters or just nothing at all, depending on how the programmer handled these cases.